# deploy play 2.1.1 framework to heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.1

im trying to deploy my app to heroku but im getting an error

i created a procfile and put this line

```
        web: target/start --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

i can push the app but when i perform this command  **heroku ps** im getting this error

```
=== web (1X): `play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS`
web.1: crashed 2013/06/15 22:17:41 (~ 2m ago)
```

and on  heroku open  im getting an application error

what im doing wrong ???

UPDATE:
i edit to procfile  and now in the logs im getting this error
**Unrecognized option: --http.port=6192**

```
2013-06-16T19:03:15.019987+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-06-16T19:05:18.689752+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by     miko5054@gmail.com
2013-06-16T19:05:18.658969+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy df1da57 by miko5054@gmail.com
2013-06-16T19:05:18.741269+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy df1da57 by miko5054@gmail.com
2013-06-16T19:05:19.331223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-06-16T19:05:20.703658+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-06-16T19:05:27.374326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command    `target/start --http.port=6192 $PLAY_OPTS`
2013-06-16T19:05:28.121197+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -     Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2013-06-16T19:05:28.121197+00:00 app[web.1]: Unrecognized option: --http.port=6192
2013-06-16T19:05:28.121197+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not create the Java virtual machine.
2013-06-16T19:05:29.501307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-06-16T19:05:29.505969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-06-16T19:05:37.540727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-06-16T19:05:37.540529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed    to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
```

**UPDATE2**

i try to fellow **nico_etkito**  advice   but
when i  remove the `Procfile` completely  this is what i got

```
  2013-06-17T15:46:00.964382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command      `target/start -Dhttp.port=27372 -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops`
  2013-06-17T15:46:03.034355+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -     Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
  2013-06-17T15:46:05.654657+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 2
  2013-06-17T15:46:08.146849+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook -         Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0.         Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

and when the  whith this `Procfile web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT}`

i got this result

```
     2013-06-17T15:53:55.937519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT}`
     2013-06-17T15:53:56.825154+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
      2013-06-17T15:54:02.003067+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 2
      2013-06-17T15:54:07.088725+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

**update3**

i almost gave up...

but i overcome the earlier problems by using 
this Procfile

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -  Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

now im getting this weird error

```
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "jmcgekjnrcomcr" is not   permitted to log in
```

this is my postgres configuration in the config file

```
   #postgres
   db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
   #db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data"
   #db.default.user=***
    #db.default.password=***
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Try a `heroku logs` to check your application logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest Heroku buildpack, the `Procfile` is optional.

If you want to use a `Procfile`, from the [Play doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionHeroku), you have to use:

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```

Comment: Are you using a database ? If so, it cannot connect to it, you must configure Heroku to connect to your db url.